# How to remove vue-snotify notifications when accidentally clicking browser's back button

Tags: vue.js, notifications, vue-router, back-button

If you open snotify confirm notification or other notifications that don't close after a while and you accidentally click browser's back button the notifications stays open

Any solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
Just add this to the router.js or wherever you initialized vue-router:

```
router.afterEach((to, from) => {
    if (Snotify.notifications.length > 0) {
    Snotify.notifications.forEach(notification => {
        Snotify.remove(notification.id)
    });
    }
});
```